# how to convert a str variable likes "xe4\xb8\xad" to Chinese?

Tags: python, unicode, character-encoding, mojibake

I have some str variables, having the form of 
 'Nov  3, 2019 16:13:05.882679000 
 \xe4\xb8\xad\xe5\x9b\xbd\xe6\xa0\x87\xe5\x87\x86\xe6\x97\xb6\xe9\x97\xb4', and I want to convert the unicode part '\xe4\xb8\xad\xe5\x9b...' to Chinese, here they mean "中国标准时间". I have tried this method :

```
t.encode('raw_unicode_escape').decode()
```

It works well when I assign the string directly to t. However, when t is a variable—— I mean do not assign the string to it,the method doesn't work.
Is there another method to solve the problem or something worry with my code?

```
from pyshark.packet.fields import LayerField
from scapy.all import *
import pyshark
from pyshark.packet.packet import Packet

capture = pyshark.LiveCapture(interface='WLAN')
capture.sniff(packet_count=10)
pkt = capture[0]  # type: Packet
time = pkt.frame_info.time.fields[0]  # type: LayerField
t=time.showname_value   # type: str
s='\xe4\xb8\xad\xe5\x9b\xbd\xe6\xa0\x87\xe5\x87\x86\xe6\x97\xb6\xe9\x97\xb4'


print(t)

print()

print(t[t.find('\\'):])
print(s)

print()

print(t[t.find('\\'):].encode('raw_unicode_escape'))
print(s.encode('raw_unicode_escape'))

------------------------ I forgot the outcome-----------
Nov  3, 2019 16:33:57.630346000 \xe4\xb8\xad\xe5\x9b\xbd\xe6\xa0\x87\xe5\x87\x86\xe6\x97\xb6\xe9\x97\xb4

\xe4\xb8\xad\xe5\x9b\xbd\xe6\xa0\x87\xe5\x87\x86\xe6\x97\xb6\xe9\x97\xb4
ä¸­å½æ åæ¶é´

b'\\xe4\\xb8\\xad\\xe5\\x9b\\xbd\\xe6\\xa0\\x87\\xe5\\x87\\x86\\xe6\\x97\\xb6\\xe9\\x97\\xb4'
b'\xe4\xb8\xad\xe5\x9b\xbd\xe6\xa0\x87\xe5\x87\x86\xe6\x97\xb6\xe9\x97\xb4'
```

Comment: There's no need to separate the timestamp and the chinese characters before decoding - the timestamp should be unaffected.  Encoding and decoding produce new objects, so you need to assign the results of these calls to variables if you want to use them in your code.  Is that the problem?

Comment: Are you using Python 2 or 3?

Comment: The "unicode part" is UTF-8 bytes. If you are using Python 3, whatever created a `str` with these contents is broken and should be fixed. If you are using Python 2, this is one of the areas where (finally!) switching to Python 3 brings significant improvements. See also https://nedbatchelder.com/text/unipain.html

Comment: @KlausD.  python3

Comment: In Python 3 encoded text should be of the type `bytes` like `s = b'\xe4\xb8\xad\xe5...'`. From there you can use `.decode(encoding)` to get a string from it.

Comment: ```print(t.encode().decode("unicode_escape").encode('raw_unicode_escape').decode())
```  this is the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The bytes that you provide are not Unicode sequences. The string "`中国标准时间`" in Unicode sequences would look like: `\u4e2d\u56fd\u6807\u51c6\u65f6\u95f4`. I can offer you to use MgntUtils java Open Source library that has a feature that converts any string in any language into a Unicode sequence and vice-versa. The code I used to convert your String into the above Unicode sequence looks like this:

```
System.out.println(StringUnicodeEncoderDecoder.encodeStringToUnicodeSequence("中国标准时间"));
```

The library can be found at [Maven Central](https://search.maven.org/artifact/com.github.michaelgantman/MgntUtils/1.5.0.8/jar) or at [Github](https://github.com/michaelgantman/Mgnt) It comes as maven artifact and with sources and javadoc

Here is javadoc for the class [StringUnicodeEncoderDecoder](http://michaelgantman.github.io/Mgnt/docs/com/mgnt/utils/StringUnicodeEncoderDecoder.html)

Comment: `The bytes that you provide are not Unicode sequences` - they are, however, a representation of the UTF-8 encoded bytestring in Python.

Answer (score 0):

This is UTF-8 incorrectly decoded as latin-1. [Mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake). To reverse it, undo the incorrect decoder and apply the correct decoder:

```
>>> s = '\xe4\xb8\xad\xe5\x9b\xbd\xe6\xa0\x87\xe5\x87\x86\xe6\x97\xb6\xe9\x97\xb4'
>>> s.encode('latin-1').decode('utf-8')
'中国标准时间'
```

*Zhōngguó biāozhǔn shíjiān* or China Standard Time according to Google translate.